# Close self-closing HTML tags on save in VS Code?

Tags: html, reactjs, visual-studio-code, jsx

When I copy HTML snippets into JSX I often get errors because self closing tags in HTML can be unclosed like `<hr>` but in JSX they must always be closed like `<hr />`, is there a plugin or setting that can automatically fix these for me?

Comment: More info about JSX self closing tag: https://react-cn.github.io/react/tips/self-closing-tag.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up solving it by doing a regex find and replace on all [void elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#void-elements).

find: `<((area|base|br|col|command|embed|hr|img|input|keygen|link|meta|param|source|track|wbr).*?[^\/])>`

replace: `<$1 />`

Comment: This regex saved me a lot of manual work. But if fails if there are line breaks within the element, for example between attributes. The `.` does not match line breaks.

Answer (score 3):

```
First you need to write below code in your settings.json

{
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll.eslint": true
      }
}


then create a .eslintrc file in root level and write this code

{
    "extends": ["react-app"],
    "rules": {
      "react/self-closing-comp": [
        "error",
        {
          "component": true,
          "html": true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used this extension with VS Code for a while now. Works really well with React in both Javascript and Typescript - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag. The doc says it works by default for the following languages. Try it and see if it is for right for your needs.

```
{
    "auto-close-tag.activationOnLanguage": [
        "xml",
        "php",
        "blade",
        "ejs",
        "jinja",
        "javascript",
        "javascriptreact",
        "typescript",
        "typescriptreact",
        "plaintext",
        "markdown",
        "vue",
        "liquid",
        "erb",
        "lang-cfml",
        "cfml",
        "HTML (Eex)"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I tried that but it only seems to work as I'm typing the tags, can't get it to correct all the self closing tags in a pasted snippet