# VSCode: auto pair to self closing React component?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Say I have a component `Foo` and when I type the follow and press `<Tab>`:

```
Foo
```

then it will become:

```
<Foo></Foo>
```

then I will insert a `/` after the first `Foo`, which leads to

```
<Foo/></Foo>
```

but I expect it to become:

```
<Foo/>
```

that is: the `</Foo>` will be auto-deleted for me. This is the behavior that IntelliJ WebStorm can do, so I'm searching a similar one for vscode. Is there any kind of plugin in visual studio code that can do this? I'm using `Visual Studio Code - Insiders` by the way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Close self-closing HTML tags on save in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64454236/close-self-closing-html-tags-on-save-in-vs-code)

Comment: @deechris27: No, I have tried the plugin mentioned in the 1-upvoted answer. It doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is just possible for "jsx" and "tsx" (i.e. TypeScript version of React component) file in the newest version of VSCode.

Emmet Abbreviation in VSCode seems to do that.

For example, typing of `div/` in "jsx" or "tsx" file becomes `<div />`